# Why doesn't the object value change? linked lists

Tags: c#

```
        static void asksomethinglater(IntNode b)//
        { 
            IntNode temp = b;
            b = b.GetNext();
            temp.SetNext(null);

        }
```

I have this code that should upadte the argument b, but when ever i run this, i have this object as an example `IntNode b = new IntNode(3, new IntNode(5, new IntNode(2)));`

The object will have only 5, with `this.next = null`

the class i use.

```
    public class IntNode
    {
        private int info;
        private IntNode next;

        public IntNode(int info)
        {
            this.info = info;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public IntNode(int info, IntNode next)
        {
            this.info = info;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public int GetInfo()
        {
            return info;
        }

        public IntNode GetNext()
        {
            return next;
        }

        public void SetInfo(int info)
        {
            this.info = info;
        }

        public void SetNext(IntNode next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if(next != null)
                return info + "-->" + next;
            return info.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Show the full code listing, we are just guessing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
static void asksomethinglater(IntNode b)
```

the variable `b` is passed by value. So the original reference was not changed.

So in this statement

```
b = b.GetNext();
```

there is being changed a copy of the original reference.

If you want to change the reference itself then you could declare the function like

```
static void asksomethinglater( ref IntNode b)
```